# Differential form on $S^1$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

I am a beginner at Manifolds. I tried the following problem, but not sure whether I got it correct not:

Find a differential 1-form on  $S^1$

My attempt:

Define $f: S^1\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y)=x$. Then definfe $df:S^1 \to \cup T_p^{*}S^1$ as, for any $p\in S^1$, $(df)_p:T_p S^1 \to \mathbb{R}$. Since $T_pS^1$ is a one dimensional vector space so take basis for it as $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}|_p \}$. Now finally,

$(df)_p(\frac{\partial}{\partial x})=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}x=1$.

Hence the differential one form on $S^1$ is $df$. Am I making sense or do my arguments have some errors?

Thanks for any insights!!

Comment: $df = 1$ doesn't mean anything. What you have is $df = dx$, more precisely the pullback of the $1$-form $dx$ on $\mathbb R^2$ to $S^1$.

Comment: @AlexProvost, okay so instead of writing $df=1$, I should write $df$ only, is that what you mean?

Comment: I mean what I said: $df = \iota^* dx$, where $\iota:S^1 \to \mathbb R^2$ is the inclusion.

Comment: By the way, it's not clear what you mean by taking $\{ \frac \partial {\partial x} \rvert_p \}$ as a basis. How is this a tangent vector at $p \in S^1$?

Comment: You use $x$ in different ways. First, you define $f(x,y)=x$ embedding $S^1$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then you define the basis as $\frac{\del}{\del x}$ where $x$ is a local coordinate. Those are different $x$’s.

Comment: @AlexProvost, I think I need to mention if $(U,\phi)$ is a chart on $S^1$ and $(U,x,y)$ than $\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}|_p , \frac{\partial}{\partial y}|_p \}= \{ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}|_p \}$ is a basis for $T_p S^1$

Comment: A chart on $S^1$ is quite different from using the coordinates from $\Bbb R^2$ as functions on $S^1$.

Comment: @TedShifrin, I did not get you. could you please point out where I went wrong

Comment: You need to tell us what is a differential form (what definition are you given?)

Comment: @ArcticChar, I am taking the standard definition that I mentioned in question as well like it is a map $df: S^1 \to \cup T^{*}_{p}S^1$

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful with local coordinates: they are indeed *local* so the expression you will get for $df$ depends on the given chart. I think some of your confusion stems from the fact that you are trying to use the ambient coordinates $(x,y)$ on $\mathbb R^2$ as local coordinates on $S^1$, as opposed to the usual approach of introducing an angular coordinate $\theta$ which reduces the amount of charts needed. Specifically, in order to make sense of your approach we need four charts

$U_x^+ = \{(x,y) \in S^1 : x > 0\}$, $U_x^- = \{(x,y) \in S^1 : x < 0\}$, $U_y^+ = \{(x,y) \in S^1 : y > 0\}$, $U_y^- = \{(x,y) \in S^1 : y < 0\}$,

as opposed to needing only two charts if we were working with an angular coordinate. For concreteness suppose that we  look at the chart $\phi:U_y^+ \to \mathbb{R}$ which flattens down the northern hemisphere, $\phi(x,y) = x$, as well as the chart $\psi:U^+_x \to \mathbb R$ which flattens the right side of the circle, $\psi(x,y) = y$. The transition maps look like $\phi \psi^{-1}(y) = x = \sqrt{1-y^2}$. So your $df$, which is just $dx$ in the first chart, takes the form $d(\sqrt{1-y^2}) = \frac{-y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} dy$ in the second chart.

In a similar vein you should be careful to note that the tangent vectors to $S^1$  denoted by $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\rvert_p$ in these coordinates are *not* the usual horizontal tangent vectors in $\mathbb R^2$. If we denote by $\iota:S^1 \to \mathbb R^2$ the inclusion then for instance $\iota \phi^{-1}(x) = (x, \sqrt{1-x^2})$ so that $\iota_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\rvert_p) = \left(1,\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)$ (which is an actual tangent vector to the unit sphere).